# HTML CSS Footer does something weird when positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am trying to make the footer move with the content. It works, but it does something very weird. When I set the position of the footer to "relative" it moves with the content as it should, but it ruins the background image as seen in the image below. If I set it back to absolute, it will be back to normal but it won't move with the content.

Seems like the bottom div won't float over the other content.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Top main div -->
    <img src="css/images/logo2.png" class="over">
    <div unselectable="on" class="top unselectable">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html"><img src="images/home2.png" class="menu" width="218" height="50" ></a></li>
        </ul> 
    </div>

    <!-- Middle main div -->
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="content">
            <p class="big">
            Hello there!
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bottom main div -->
    <div class="bottom">

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.wrapper
{
    min-height:100%;
    min-width: 1280px; 
    position:relative; /*most likely the problem. There's a dispute between this and the footer attribute*/
}

div.top
{
    height:100px;
    background-color:grey;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background: url('images/top.png');
}

div.middle
{
    background-color:blue;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background: url(images/bg_middle.png);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

div.content
{
    background: url(images/content.png);
    width: 800px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #373737;
    margin: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000000;
}

div.bottom
{
    height:78px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:white;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background: url(images/bottom.png);
    position:relative; /* Conflicts with the wrapper. */
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Image with position:absolute
[image]

Image with position: relative
[image]

Comment: What do you mean when you say you want the "footer to move with the content"? Setting an element as position:relative has no real effect in the implementation you show here. Setting an element as position:absolute takes it out of the normal flow of the document, causing other elements to ignore it when calculating their position.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

This is what I mean. When I add content to the page(more text) it has to move the footer down(out of the way). Otherwise the text will overlap.

Comment: What I do when debugging, is I add 'border:1px solid' to my divs or any other element so I can see exactly where they start and end, where they might overlap, and whatever. It is so much easier.

Comment: Something along these lines? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kmGcz

Comment: Yes, only when I do it, my footer does that weird thing like the the images above. Somehow a white stripe appears behind my footer.

Comment: I added the other bit of my code.

Comment: @BogdanLazar The trick here is to have a wrapping element around your content and footer with a "position:relative".

Comment: @Celmar Exactly what I did from the beginning. I have updated my html code as well. As you can see, I wrapped everything. Removing the 2nd "position: relative" from the footer does nothing.

Comment: I managed to figure out that my "wrapper" is most likely the problem.

Answer (score 1):

How about you use same `position: absolute` on the footer and `padding-bottom` on the `.content`?

```
div.content {
    padding-bottom: 78px;//height of the footer
}
```

Comment: Please review my code and see if you can find the proper implementation. I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Updated the answer please check if this answer you question.

Comment: Then the footer will float over the content and it won't move with it anymore. If I set the footer to absolute, then it will float over the content in a fixed position. If I set it to relative, it won't float anymore over the other elements like the webpage background, but instead push it up and place itself at the bottom, creating a white background.

Comment: So you want footer to be fixed? When you scroll it must keep at the bottom yes? Could you upload images online and use them in `jsfidle` for me to see what exact problem you have? Now I am not sure what you need :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the div up a bit: top and z-index. Only z-index if it isn't on top.

```
div.bottom
{
    height:78px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:white;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background: url(images/bottom.png);
    position:relative;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    top:-15px;
    z-index:2;
}
```

Comment: That leaves me with a white line at the bottom that the footer doesn't cover. Also that white line is what makes the background of the footer look bad(washed up).

Comment: adjust the height to be more than 78px

Comment: or, move the upper div down, either way.

Comment: For that to work, I'd have to recreate the image in Photoshop to be taller(original one is only 78px). I believe there is a better solution for my problem.